# HTML - How to download image if served from CDN?

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have an image link that download directly when it's clicked.

I successfully done so by adding this to the `.htaccess`:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .jpg
AddType application/octet-stream .png
AddType application/octet-stream .svg
```

Then I installed CDN plugin (it's WordPress site) that automatically change all image link to the new CDN link.

```
// before
<a href="mysite.com/.../my-image.jpg">

// after
<a href="some-cdn.com/.../my-image.jpg">
```

But now when I click it, it goes to new tab since the image is no longer served from my server.

Any solution to this?

So far I found **download attribute** (but has bad [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)) and [**hacky iframe**](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/) trick but I prefer cleaner solution, if any.

Comment: I use the "hacky" jquery.fileDownload and it works for me.  YMMV

Comment: @JohnHascall I tried that and it does works. But I get this warning: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:`. Did you get this too?